# Exception when using SqlReader

Tags: c#, database, ado.net

I tried to call this method from multiple threads trying to get the ID from the same string. I am always getting this exception at the line where I create the SqlDataReader:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which
>   must be closed first.

I don't know where the problem is. I am using a lock() statement so I use the command only once, then I dispose it. Kinda new to database programming so I don't know where my error is.

Thanks!

```
public int UsernameGetID(string username)
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT user_id FROM " + ServerConstants.Database.TableUserInformation + " WHERE username = @Username", connection))
    {
        lock (command)
        {
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar, username.Length);
            param.Value = username;
            command.Parameters.Add(param);
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    return (int)reader[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    // username doesn't exists
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you do not share the `connection` variable, but create the connection in the `UsernameGetID` method itself?

Comment: You are using an opened connection from previous or some other SqlDataReader

Comment: wouldn't it hurt performance? I would like to use only one connection as I don't want to create a connection instance every time I fetch something from my databases. I have only one connection and all the commands are done on it. Is that a bad thing to do?

Comment: Are you using the same `connection` for other readers? If yes, you can try to add `MultipleActiveResultSets=true;` to the end of the connection string. Or just create a new `SqlConnection`

Comment: @Pacha: Yes, it is. It's error prone, as you've discovered. The connection pool will handle this for you - it won't *really* create a new network connection each time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Locking on `command` is pointless, given that you're creating a new command within the method - no other code *could* lock on it.

However, you're sharing the *connection* between multiple commands. Don't do that - create a new `SqlConnection` (again, in a `using` statement) in each call. Don't worry about the efficiency aspect - the connection pool will take care of the "real" network connection.

So you want:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(..., connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    ...
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        return reader.Read() ? (int) reader[0] : 0;
    }
}
```